# Testing whether two vectors are increasing or decreasing in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I was wondering if there might be a way in base R to test whether two vectors (BOTH OF THEM) are increasing or decreasing?

For example, the test should return `FALSE` when testing `a` and `b` (see below) and the test should return `TRUE`when testing `c` and `d` (see below).

```
a = 5:10
b = 10:5
c = seq(-5, 15)
d = seq(-15, -8)
```

For clarity,  I'm asking any **two vectors** (when both ordered but regardless of their length) if are **decreasing** (e.g., `10:0`, `100:97`, `-8:-10`) then the test  should return TRUE, else if the two vectors are both increasing again the test should return TRUE, else should return FALSE.

Comment: Why is 5:10 not increasing? EDIT: now I see after your edit, test (a, b) and (c, d).

Comment: If `x` is increasing, does `y` also have to be increasing for this to be `TRUE`? Or can `x` and `y` go in different directions as long as they're monotonic?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question was not very clear. Give examples of different inputs and the outputs you expect to make sure people can understand what you're asking.

Comment: What an important question!! sorry not sure who and why really got this question downvoted!

Comment: OK, I don't think Ben's answer works for decreasing vectors (try it). If your question is not clear you'll get answers that that don't meet your requirements, and that's not the fault of the answerers.

Comment: Does the "increasing" here mean monotonically increasing, strictly increasing, or just have a increasing trend?

Comment: @Cory, just have a increasing trend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Both vectors increasing" would be

```
all(diff(x)>0) && all(diff(y)>0)
```

"Both vectors decreasing" would be

```
all(diff(x)<0) && all(diff(y)<0)
```

You could combine these with `||` (or).

Comment: It might be helpful to modify it to look like a function since it's for any two arbitrary vectors?

Comment: Ben, your answer has a problem, make a simple function out of it: `uneq.vec = function(x, y) all(diff(x) > 0) && all(diff(y) > 0)` then test what OP is asking. Your formulation fails when two vectors are decreasing as an example: `uneq.vec(x = 10:5, y = 4:0)`, in this case OP needs a TRUE while your formulation returns FALSE

Comment: This solution has a drawback because it requires strictly increase to be TRUE. However, according to @parvin, `uniq.vec(c(1,2,1,4,5), c(5:10))` should also be TRUE instead of FALSE.

Comment: the OP has not been particularly clear about this (and they did accept my answer).  I'd rather they edited their question with concrete examples to confirm what "have an increasing trend" means; does that mean e.g. that the slope of a linear regression is positive?

Comment: Yes I know it wasn't very clear. So I would say always make the OP clarify the question before giving answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to @parvin, the definition of "increasing" is just "having an increasing trend". So I suggest that instead of using `diff`, we use `lm`.

Say I have two numeric vector, `x` and `y`, here is my solution:

```
unname(!xor(lm(x ~ seq_along(x))$coefficient[2] > 0, lm(y ~ seq_along(y))$coefficient[2] > 0))
```

`xor` fulfills exactly the need so we can get rid of combining two statements with `|` or `||`. `unname` is used to simply delete the coefficient name.